# MATLAB How to replace real values with NaN and NaN with real values

Tags: arrays, matlab, nan

I have the following matrix

```
xx = [ 1 2 3 4; NaN NaN 7 8];
```

I want to change `xx` to be:

```
yy = [ NaN NaN NaN NaN; 88 88 NaN NaN];
```

I have the following script

```
for i = 1:2;
    for j = 1:4;
        if (xx(i,j) ~= NaN)
            yy(i,j) = NaN;
        else
            yy(i,j) = 88;
        end
    end
end
xx
yy
```

But I have the unwanted result, because

```
yy =

   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for loops. Just use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
yy = xx; % initiallize yy to xx
ind = isnan(xx); % logical index of NaN values in xx
yy(ind) = 88; % replace NaN with 88
yy(~ind) = NaN; % replace numbers with NaN
```

Anyway, the problem with your code is that `xx(i,j) ~= NaN` always gives `true`. `NaN` doesn't equal anything, by definition. To check if a value is `NaN` you need the [`isnan`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) function. So you should use `~isnan(xx(i,j))` in your code:

```
for i = 1:2;
    for j = 1:4;
        if ~isnan(xx(i,j))
            yy(i,j) = NaN;
        else
            yy(i,j) = 88;
        end
    end
end
```

Also, consider [preallocating](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) `yy` for speed. For example, you could initiallize `yy` with all entries equal to `88`, and then you can remove the `else` branch:

```
yy = repmat(88, size(xx));
for i = 1:2;
    for j = 1:4;
        if ~isnan(xx(i,j))
            yy(i,j) = NaN;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @User1961 Glad I could help